# Highcharts solid gauge with multiple series

Tags: highcharts

With a bit of fiddling, I can get multiple series to display nicely in a Highcharts solid gauge:

```
    series: [{
        data: [50],
        innerRadius:'120%',
    }, {
        data: [83],
        innerRadius:'110%'
    }, {
        data: [19],
        innerRadius:'90%'
    }]
```

http://jsfiddle.net/gc323yu6/1/

But this only looks right if the data is carefully arranged. When I try to display arbitrary values, this kind of thing happens:

http://jsfiddle.net/gc323yu6/

How can I display multiple series properly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Now simply add `radius` option: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/gc323yu6/535/

```
    series: [{
        data: [83],
        innerRadius:'110%',
        radius: '120%'
    }, {
        data: [50],
        innerRadius:'100%',
        radius: '110%'
    }, {
        data: [19 ],
        innerRadius:'80%',
        radius: '90%'
    }]
```

Comment: Do you know if is possible to each serie set min, max and stops? Instead of use a shared for all the series? Thank you so much!

Comment: You can add separate yAxis for each series, but what should happen to labels?

Comment: @Pawel. How about having stacked series? So, next datapoint would be a continuation of the prev. datapoint.

Comment: Not really a stacking, but simply adding more points looks fine: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/1ez48dab/ (data should be sorted in the descending order)